# Spring Data JPA map 2 tables with same java Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

im working on spring projet ,
i have the following tables :

```
user
----------------------
ID | salary | status |
---------------------
 1 |15000   | active |
----------------------
...
```

and i have my user entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User{
    
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private Double salary;

  private String status;
  
  //....
    
}
```

now i will create  a new table to store history of my user with onetoMany , this is my table :

```
user_history
------------------------------
ID |ID_USER| salary | status |
------------------------------
 1 |  1    |15000   | active |
-----------------------------
 2 |  1    |16000   | inactiv|
-----------------------------
...
```

and i want to use the same java User entity to store the user object in my new user_history table.
do you have any idea how i can do this

Comment: Not a direct answer maybe but I think you should have a look at spring data envers, no need to reinvent the wheel: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/envers/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: Please use Hibernate Enver Audits. See here: https://github.com/enexusde/Java-Spring-Boot-JPA-Enver-Audit-Hibernate-Tools-Reversengineer/blob/master/src/main/java/de/e_nexus/codereview/audit/CoolHistory.java